# Javascript PhP mailing Doesnt work in new project

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to integrate an old mailing script I have from a past project to my new site. The process involves a javascript and a php script in the following manner.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
  function send_mail() {
      var subject = document.getElementById('subject').value;
      var message = document.instanceById('message').getContent();
      var params = 'subject='+subject+'&message='+message;
      if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest(); }
      else { xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP'); }
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
          if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) { document.getElementById('result').innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText; }
      }
      document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'Message is sending.. please wait..';
      xmlhttp.open('POST', 'scripts/newsletter-mail.php', true);
      xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
      xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
      xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
      xmlhttp.send(params);
  }
</script>
```

**The form :**

```
    <label><strong>Title</strong></label>                               
                <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" class="form-control" value="">
                <br>
                    </div>  
            <div class="col-md-12">                     
              <label><strong>Main Text</strong></label>
<textarea class="summernote" id="text" name="message" id="message" data-plugin-summernote data-plugin-options='{ "height": 300, "codemirror": { "theme": "ambiance" } }'></textarea>
<input class="button" type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Send Email" onclick="send_mail();" />
```

**An the php script**

```
     @error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
  session_cache_limiter('nocache, must-revalidate');
  session_start();


  include_once '../../scripts/mysql.lib.php';
  $mysql = new mysql(TRUE);

$serv = $mysql->fetch("SELECT * FROM server ;", FALSE); 
$host = $serv['host'];


  $limit = 100;

  $subject = $_POST['subject'];
  $message = $_POST['message'];
  $headers[] = 'From: My Address';
  $headers[] = 'X-Priority: 5';
  $headers[] = 'MIME-Version: 1.0';
  $headers[] = 'Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"' . "\r\n";
  $hlist = implode("\r\n", $headers);

  $result = 1;
  $list = $mysql->fetch('SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM newsletter;', FALSE);
  $count = $list['count'];
  $emails = $mysql->fetch("SELECT email_id, email FROM newsletter WHERE status = 'none' LIMIT $limit;", TRUE);
  if ($mysql->num_rows > 0) {
      $sent = array();
      $error = array();
      foreach($emails as $email) {
          $msg = $message . "\r\n<br /><br />" . '<small>If you wish to unregister from our newsletter list please click  <a href="'.$host .'/unsubscribe.php?email=' . $email['email'] . '&code=' . $email['code'] . '">Here</a></small>';
          if (@mail($email['email'], $subject, $msg, $hlist)) { $sent[] = $email['email_id']; }
          else { $error[] = $email['email_id']; }
          unset($msg);
      }
      $updsent = $mysql->query("UPDATE newsletter SET status = 'sent' WHERE email_id IN('" . implode("','",$sent) . "');");
      $upderror = $mysql->query("UPDATE newsletter SET status = 'error' WHERE email_id IN('" . implode("','",$error) . "');");
      switch(TRUE) {
          case (count($error) == 0): $result = 3; break;
          case (count($error) == $mysql->num_rows): $result = 4; break;
          case (count($error) > 0): $result = 5; break;
      }
  }
  if (($result == 1) && ($count > 0)) { $result = 2; }

  switch($result) {
      case 1: echo 'No Email Address in List - Message was not sent.'; break;
      case 2: echo 'All User have received the Message'; break;
      case 3: echo 'Message Sent!<br />(Cont. Sending  ..)'; break;
      case 4: echo 'Error - Message was not sent.'; break;
      case 5: echo 'Message Sent to some User.<br />(Cont. Sending..)'; break;
  }


?>
```

In the Html above the form there exist a div  to grab results.

In short, after migrating the code to my project, nothing works what so ever. Nothing is sent, no result appear in the result div and my URL bar gets back the following:

```
newsletter-mail.php?subject=This is a title &message=<p>This is a test message<%2Fp>&submit=Send+Email
```

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: sounds like the javascript isnt being triggered.. is this form actually wrapped in `<form>` tags? if so, perhaps adding an `attachEventListener` to the submit of the form would work better

Comment: Looks like your code is wrapped inside `<form>`, but you do not need a form for this script. Go on and add `return false;` at the end of `send_mail();` function;Also, make sure you have all required IDs on page (subject, message, result).

Comment: The removal of the form tags only solved the problem of getting the vars in the URL bar. Still there is no activity registering. Its like the php script is not invoked...

Comment: Also this line is not invoked as well...  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'Message is sending.. please wait..'; Which means that the script is not working really, right ????